# Possible to Prototype ALL Objects

Tags: javascript, prototype

In javascript, is there a way to prototype all objects. A simple usecase would be, I have a function:

```
testFn(el) {
    if(el.isElement()) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Here I would like to test if the object passed into the function is a DOM element. Normally I would use this function:

```
function isElement(el) {
    if(typeof el == 'object' && 'nodeType' in el && el.nodeType === 1 && el.cloneNode) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I find myself rewriting this code over and over again. It would be nice if I could simply prototype Object and have this function available on the fly for every object, whenever I might need it. Prototyping Object seems to give me errors though.

Comment: When you alter Object.prototype, you might well feel ill effects. Is there a subset of objects, like those you might define yourself, that you could settle for? Otherwise ALL other objects in code you run will have a modified prototype, and thus (if you don't use ES5's Object.defineProperty) a modified for..in context for iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to prototype all objects

You can use `prototype` on `Object`:

```
Object.prototype.isElement = function () {
    return typeof this == 'object' && 'nodeType' in this && this.nodeType === 1 && this.cloneNode
}
```

Comment: Isn't `typeof this` always going to return "object"?

Comment: http://www.websanova.com/tutorials/javascript/extending-javascript-the-right-way explains how to extend Object protoypes more safely.